# Repartitioning Internal Memory of Android Device

Tags: internal-storage, partitions

How can I repartition my device such that the storage for device internal usage (i.e application storage or internal memory) can be increased in lieu of decreasing the User available memory.

Currently, I have:

- Internal memory = 740 MB
- User Available Space = 2.0 GB

How can I repartition to move some Phone Storage/User Available Space to Internal Memory?

I have an External SD card for Media Storage. So, I don't require 2 GB in the phone storage.

Comment: That's not possible. But you might wish to see: [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) and our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Comment: @TSDCR Would it be possible to mention your phone model and manufacturer in this question as well. This will allow us to clearly answer your question in detail.

Comment: You may also take a look at this question in order to solve your issue -> http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24164/repartitioning-htc-sensation-4gb-internal-memory-for-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem the best way was to do the following:

1. Root the phone (do it t your own risk!!!! - I sure did and works fine).
2. Install any memory management application (RAM Management app - refer XDA forum).

3.It will ask you to allocate some of your internal memory as SWAP space.

4. When done you will have the SWAP act as a backup RAM in case the internal RAM is full.

That did work for me and phone is working faster since then (only small lags while playing HD games)..

Note ; done this before 5 Months sorry for the late update

Comment: It's a bad idea to use internal storage as swap.  Use an SD card instead.  If/when the storage wears out from swapping, it's the difference between a new $15 SD card and a new $500 phone.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* repartition the internal memory. In essence it can be done, but what many others have answered is basically correct. Not only is it quite difficult and risky to perform it, it also requires specialized skills which the average user may not have. There is one solution to the problem though.

The easiest way to do this is to look for a custom ROM for your phone. Many custom ROM providers recognize the issue already and have a fix for it in some way or the other.

Your phone model can provide more information if you like.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your question correctly, the answer is: You can't. The internal memory is built into the phone and can not be altered, hence why many phones come with SD card expansion option. Those that do not will either have high internal memory from the get-go, or are simply not meant to function beyond basic phone functions (such as call and SMS).

If it is simply a question of optimizing the use of your internal memory, I answered a thread that was roughly about that here: [Gmail won't sync, apps don't update: "Device doesn't have enough storage space"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64651/gmail-wont-sync-apps-dont-update-device-doesnt-have-enough-storage-space/64791#64791)

Comment: if both the memory are partitions of the same device then is it possible to reformat and extend the internal memory.