# Can I format android phone's internal storage with adb?

Tags: adb, formatting

I formatted my phones internal storage with ntfs and now it doesn't appeared in usb mode and also not in file manager. And phone's feature like gallery, camera, recording etc are not working. Is there any way to format internal storage again with fat32 file system? I think there should be a way in ADB to format it. I don't have much knowledge about it but think it is easiest way!!! Please someone help me....

Comment: How did you reformat it in the first place? Why not just do that again?

Comment: And for the next time remember to first check which file systems are supported by your device. NTFS is definetely NOT. Whether FAT will work on internal storage is another thing; today's devices rather use EXTFS internally (and FAT for the external cards). If you remember the file system used before, I strongly recommend reverting to that. For what possibilities exist, you need to provide more details: Device rootet (obviously yes), custom-recovery or stock?

Comment: I attached my phone via USB and make it rooted,  and easily done that. And then I format my Internal storage with NTFS without any reason(may be bad luck or to know more about android). And after that when I remove USB the Internal Storage vanished from every where (from Settings, File Manager and also does not shows in USB mode on laptop, so that i cant reformat it again. and

Comment: and worst part is my gallery, camera, recording, Whats app videos & Images approximately all features related to storage doesn't work. But now everything is alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I found some instructions here that partially apply: http://androidandme.com/2009/08/news/how-to-manually-partition-your-sd-card-for-android-apps2sd/

**DO TAKE CARE, IF YOU DO NOT UNDERSTAND COMMANDS WELL, DONT TRY THIS OUT**.

The difference is that you just want one partition in fat32.
`mkpartfs primary fat32 0 [last MB]` # where last MB is visible using `parted /dev/block/mmcblkXXXXXXXX` . Also the article is about an sdcard.

I'd recommend checking carefully if you have the right block level device before issuing any partitioning commands!

When using the appropriate block level device, little can go wrong, as you currently have no access at all.

[edit]
Personally, I'd try to install a new recovery using Fastboot, and then use that recovery to format your internal storage. A lot easier and safer IMO.

Comment: thanks for reply and help...i will try and tell u what happen...
thanx

Comment: I tried factory reset but nothing was happened.

Comment: i tried the link methed and got this error...what should i do now?


Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh
table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.

Comment: @AJKumar The internal SD is not the same as the EXT SD at all in this regard. Do you have a PIT file for your device? Can you just do what you did earlier, but the right way? Why would you partition he internal memory? Each device has its own internal partition structure (PIT file usually  handles this) and partitioning the internal memory is a guaranteed bricked device. I don't think the above answer will work at all for INT SD. The EXT SD is usually one FAT32 partition or  a FAT 32 and an EXT 2/3/4 if needed, the Internal partitioning is hugely complicated in comparison.

Comment: See [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65781/repartitioning-internal-memory-of-android-device) and this part is important: `You can repartition the internal memory. In essence it can be done, but what many others have answered is basically correct. Not only is it quite difficult and risky to perform it, it also requires specialized skills which the average user may not have.` Flagging this for closure as it could cause other users to further brick their  devices. Android needs **/boot  /system  /recovery /data /cache /misc** partitions in place, AND the **/SD**

Comment: Thanx for ur suggestion....but i dont want to repartition the internal memory, i want it back in my phone means it vanished from everywhere causing many media features of the phone stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it cant believe...............
I find a command on a website where i just place my mmcblk number that I known via Paragon exFAT,NTFS&HFS+.apk app and run this command as a Super user
  " mkfs.vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p33 "
and now i got my internal storage back on my phone.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you did and tidy up this answer as it could be very useful to others who have this issue. I'm not sure what site you are talking about and the steps you took.

Comment: I install Paragon exFAT,NTFS&HFS+.apk app on my phone to mount internal storage, this app capable to mount ntfs file system memory in your android device and have feature of Fix and Format (but only with NTFS and HFS,). with the FIX feature it run something and said fixed somewhere mmcblk0p28. And while I'm searching on google just find out a command formatting "mkfs.vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p33"

Comment: (here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1926780 )

Comment: formatting something related to my issue "mkfs.vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p33" and I replaced the "mmcblk0p" number with mine "mmcblk0p28" and run it as Super User in ADB and woa!! it format the internal storage and get back the internal storage on phone.