# Huawei Ascend Y300 - only 1GB space for applications available

Tags: applications, internal-storage, huawei

I have a Huawei Ascend Y300 phone. It has a total of 4 GB internal flash memory and 2 GB of those are accessible by user. However, of those 2 GB only approximately 1 GB can be used for applications and the rest can be used for other user files (photos etc.). Like this, the number of applications that fit into 1 GB is greatly limited...

Is there a way to make the application storage bigger and maybe grow it to the whole 2 GB? Do I need to root the device for that? One can set the SD card as default storage location but still part of the applications seem to be installed to internal storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these were made a lot of times, and require the repartition of the internal memory.

As you can read in  [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65781/repartitioning-internal-memory-of-android-device) , this requires a custom ROM.

I own an Huawei Y300 too, and I've found lots of ROMs and information [there](http://www.modaco.com/forum/736-huawei-ascend-g510-orange-daytona-y300-g330/)