# How to repartition Google Nexus 4 (aka. LG E960)?

Tags: nexus-4, partitions

Over a month ago, LineageOS rolled out [Oreo (I think) update for the Nexus 4 (mako)](https://download.lineageos.org/mako), but there's a catch - the system now takes up so much space, that even the nano version of [open-gapps](https://opengapps.org/) package can no longer be installed without manually removing application in-between the installations. I thought, rather than shooting down apps from default LineageOS, I would rather bump the **system** partition's size by another 200 MiB.

I haven't attempted anything yet, as information how to achieve this on a snapdragon device seems to be very sparse - is it even possible? I've done repartitioning on a Mediatek device, where doing so involved hand-editing an MBR-like partition table and uploading it to the device using [SP-flashtool](https://spflashtool.com/). Is there a similar, or perhaps an easier-to-use tool for Snapdragon devices?

P.S. - I've read the answers/suggestions to [question 65781](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/65781/251861), and none of them are helpful to my question.

Comment: Well, it turns out the flash-tool shenanigans are specific to Mediatek, and partitioning on other phones is done with plain GPT on the mmcblk0 device. So I should be able to resize partitions with generic tools like `parted`, or `sgdisk` (neither of which is available in TWRP,  but shouldn't be hard to get).Will write up a full answer once I actually get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the Nexus 4 uses plain GPT on its storage to split it up into partitions. Any tool able to modify GPT should work. By far the biggest problem for me was *getting* an appropriate tool - the `fdisk` bundled with TWRP can only list partitions on a GPT disk, without making any changes. I prefer not to use `parted` (available from [Termux](https://termux.com/)), due to its inability to display/modify partition GUIDs (may have changed since the last time I checked).

Looking back, it may be possible to dump the entire storage to a computer, make changes there, and put the whole thing back, but I specifically wanted to avoid writing over critical partitions (loaders, kernel, etc.), so I set out to get [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) for android.

I eventually found [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2608337), where the author prepared an archive with `gdisk` and a few other tools.

### Requirements:

- Computer/VM with `adb`, `fsck.ext4` and `resize2fs`
- [This zip file](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23311191640113401)

### Overview

The relevant partitions (`system` and `userdata`) are 21st and 23rd on the storage. The 22nd partition is just `cache`, so there's no harm nuking it, and making a new one after data from the other 2 are in place.

The TL;DR version of the procedure is:

- pull the data partition to computer

  ```
  [PC] adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p23 userdata.img
  ```
- put gdisk on the phone, and use it to modify the partition table - grow `system` while retaining its starting sector, shrink `userdata` by the same amount, and re-create `cache` between them

  ```
  [PC] adb push gdisk /tmp/
  [adb-shell] /tmp/gdisk /dev/block/mmcblk0
  ...
  ```
- use `resize2fs` on the phone with the `system` partition to grow it
- use `resize2fs`on the computer with the `userdata` partition's image to shrink it to appropriate size
- push the modified `data` image to the phone

  ```
  [PC] adb push userdata.img /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
  ```
- format the cache partition, reboot into system